# rgl plot3d plotting points (spheres) with vertical lines to x–y plane

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I am using `rgl` `plot3d` function to plot 3d points from Multidimensional scaling. So far I can draw the points as spheres using `type="s"`, I can rotate the plots as I need:

```
plot3d(x,y,z,type = "s", col=rainbow(20), size= 4,xlab="F1",ylab="F2",zlab="F3",main=title.main,box=TRUE,top=TRUE).
```

I know that I can get this using `rgl` `scatter3d` function but this is used scatters/regression ... and I can also do this with `scatterplot3d`, but I can't rotate this one. I would have imagined that if it is possible to do this using `rgl` `scatter3d` function. I would expect that it would be easy in `rgl` `plot3d` function... but I haven't figure out how to plot these vertical lines from the `points(spheres)` using `plot3d`? If I use `type = "h"` it only draws vertical lines to the x–y plane and I don't see a separate parameter to draw the spheres.

Comment: Follow plot3d(... , type='h') by points3d

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
> x=1:10
> y=21:30
> z=51:60

> plot3d(x,y,z, type='s')
> plot3d(x,y,z, type='h',add=TRUE)
```

[image]